# Recovery data Postgres 14

Tags: postgresql

- I used Jpa hibernate with config spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
- My database driver is PostgreSQL 14
- Can I back up to state by PID of session log in pgAdmin?

[image: pgAdmin4]

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: What exactly does "*back up to state*" man?

Comment: Can you see the image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L043r.png). I need rollback by PID of session tab of Pgadmin4

Comment: You can't rollback a different transaction. But you can kill the backend using ` pg_terminate_backend ()` which would implicitly doe a rollback